# Autohotkey Input Times Out Because MatchList Isn't Matched

Tags: autohotkey

Here's my AHK script

```
:*:if ::
SendInput IF{Space}
Input cond, I V T5,, then
msgbox %ErrorLevel%
msgbox %cond%
if (ErrorLevel = "Match")
    {
    SendInput {Enter}End If{Space}'%cond%
    }
Return
```

When I type `If x = 1 then` I get an ErrorLevel of 'Timeout' and a cond of 'x = 1 then'

My understanding is that when I type `then` it's supposed to stop the Input and set the ErrorLevel to Match.

I've tried putting it in quotes, using single letters in the MatchList, and including and end key, but none of works. The few examples I could find of using MathList look just like mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
Input cond, I V T5 *,,% " then"
```

Without the asterisk option, an item in MatchList needs to be the next thing typed. So `If Then` would match *then* in the MatchList. But `If anything then` doesn't match `then` in the MatchList because it's trying to match `anything then`, not just `then`.

With the asterisk option, `if anything then` is matched because the next thing typed after If contained `then`. That causes problems if you type `if heathen then` because the `then` in `heathen` triggers it. The space before `then` should fix that, but it doesn't.

AHK help says that the MatchList respects spaces, but it doesn't seem to do that when the space is before the first (or only) item in MatchList. The two ways around that are to include a dummy word at the beginning or to use the `%` thingy to quote the MathList item and include the space.

See also http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3979

Comment: Alternative to the "`%` thingy" you could use `%A_Space%then`

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using [RegEx powered hotstrings](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/15015-regex-powered-dynamic-hotstrings/?p=98040) for this purpose:

```
#Include <Hotstrings>
hotstrings("if (.*?) then", "If %$1% then``nEnd If%A_SPACE%")
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like something that would require regex. I'm just looking for one word. Is there some reason that you recommend it over the built-in way?

Comment: @DickKusleika What about flexibility and ease of implementation? Certainly nothing *requires* regex, it's just an easy way of matching things, as evidenced by the amount of code in your script and mine. You're right that it doesn't solve your specific `Input` problem, but it offers a solution to the whole problem, and is applicable to basically any dynamic hotstring problem; rendering `Input` moot at this point. Counterquestion: Why *wouldn't* you use regex, since it's less effort, more dynamic and more readable?

Comment: Because regex is hard :) Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of "T" in the AutoHotkey Help File states this:

```
T: Timeout (e.g. T3). The number of seconds to wait before terminating the 
Input and setting ErrorLevel to the word Timeout. If the Input times out, 
OutputVar will be set to whatever text the user had time to enter.
```

Basically, this is saying exactly what is to be expected (and what is actually happening) with your script. So, for me when I type "if x = 1 then" my "if" is immediately replaced with the caps lock IF and a space.

After 5 seconds, the first MsgBox appears with "Timeout" as the text (again, expected since ErrorLevel is set to the word "Timeout" when the "T" option is present). Once that MsgBox is dismissed, I receive the second MsgBox which (according to the help file) contains OutputVar which is what I (the user) had time to enter in before the Timeout.

Comment: It should only timeout if it doesn't match something in MatchList. Why did it timeout when you typed "then" because "then" is in the MatchList?

Comment: It times out no matter what when you add the T option. If you can help me understand what it is you're trying to accomplish, I can probably help you out a bit more. But, as it stands your script is working as the help file states.